# How do I examine which kind of digitizer hardware for inductive stylus is built in my tablet?

Tags: windows-10, hardware-rec, windows-tabletpc, pen, stylus

I guess there are only 3 OEMs of these pen devices? this should be N-trig (MS Surface, Sony), Wacom (Galaxy Notes?) and Synaptics (Acer, Dell etc.).

I just tested a new (noname) Windows Tablet with digitizer coming to the stores in these days, but the optional advertised stylus seems far from being delivered to the stores.

I would like to test some of existing pens in the mean time.

Which are most likely working? Can I check some system driver of the tablet to see the technology it supports?
Any further ideas?

Comment: I may add or send some ACPI dumps for this, if it helps?

Answer (score 2):

the best way to determine is to check for a vendor-specific driver in the HID section of the device manager to get a hint at least....

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/480473)

Comment: @Ramhound I still think it seem a good way to evaluate the quality of the answer. I do not need to accept it, but depending on upvotes I see some agreements....

Comment: You indicate what the best way is, but you don't describe the process, this answer appeared in the review for a reason.